# How can I solve this error with the .getparent method in Java to rename a file?

Tags: java, file, file-rename

I write here cause I'm struggling to rename a file.
I have created  a java swing interface to rename a file by choosing the file with a button and then rename it with the new name that the user puts in the input field.
But once I try to link the selected file I have errors displayed in the methods .getparent() and renameto()
Could you give me a hand please? 
The error I get it is:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.lang.Object.getParent
Thanks

```
package dpo3_ea_a3_mala;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class CatFileManager extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private Object file;

    /**
     * Creates new form CatFileManager
     */
    public CatFileManager() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        DescriptionSelectFile1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        DescriptionSelectFile2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Background = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        Logo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Create = new javax.swing.JButton();
        SelectRename = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Read = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Delete = new javax.swing.JButton();
        DescriptionCreate = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        InputCreate = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        ReadArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        DescriptionSelectFile = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        CreateArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        DescriptionSelectFile3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        RenameName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        RenameInput = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        DeleteDescription = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        DescriptionSelectFile1.setText("Selecciona el archivo a leer:");

        DescriptionSelectFile2.setText("Selecciona el archivo a leer:");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Background.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 255, 255));
        Background.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, new java.awt.Color(204, 51, 255)));

        Logo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/dpo3_ea_a3_mala/Cat.png"))); // NOI18N
        Logo.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, new java.awt.Color(204, 51, 255)));

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Hiragino Kaku Gothic StdN", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("CAT FILE MANAGER");

        Create.setText("Crear");
        Create.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                CreateActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        SelectRename.setText("Seleccionar");
        SelectRename.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                SelectRenameActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Read.setText("Leer este Archivo Ya!");
        Read.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ReadActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Delete.setText("Archivo para Eliminar");
        Delete.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                DeleteActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        DescriptionCreate.setText("Nombre el archivo:");

        ReadArea.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 204, 255));
        ReadArea.setColumns(20);
        ReadArea.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(ReadArea);

        DescriptionSelectFile.setText("Selecciona el archivo a leer:");

        CreateArea1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 204, 255));
        CreateArea1.setColumns(20);
        CreateArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(CreateArea1);

        DescriptionSelectFile3.setText("Selecciona el archivo a renombrar:");

        RenameName.setText("Nuevo nombre del archivo:");

        RenameInput.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                RenameInputActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setText("Renombrar");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        DeleteDescription.setText("Selecciona el archivo a eliminar:");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout BackgroundLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(Background);
        Background.setLayout(BackgroundLayout);
        BackgroundLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            BackgroundLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(186, 186, 186)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(Logo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 172, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(DescriptionCreate))
                    .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(DescriptionSelectFile3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(SelectRename, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(DeleteDescription)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(Delete, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 258, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                        .addGap(19, 19, 19))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(DescriptionSelectFile)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(Read, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGap(13, 13, 13))
                    .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(RenameName)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(RenameInput)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 129, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(Create, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 280, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(InputCreate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 153, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(19, 19, 19))))
            .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(184, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 274, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(19, 19, 19)))
        );
        BackgroundLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            BackgroundLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(DescriptionCreate)
                            .addComponent(InputCreate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(4, 4, 4)
                        .addComponent(Create))
                    .addComponent(Logo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 210, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Read)
                    .addComponent(DescriptionSelectFile))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(DescriptionSelectFile3)
                    .addComponent(SelectRename))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(RenameName)
                    .addComponent(RenameInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(DeleteDescription)
                    .addComponent(Delete))
                .addContainerGap(31, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(BackgroundLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(126, 126, 126)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(298, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(Background, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(Background, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 6, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void CreateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String nombreArchivo=InputCreate.getText();
 String carpeta = System.getProperty("user.dir");
 String direccionCompleta= carpeta+"/"+nombreArchivo+".txt";
 FileWriter ubicacion = null;
 try {
 ubicacion = new FileWriter(direccionCompleta);
 } catch (IOException ex) {
 Logger.getLogger(crear.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
 try{
 BufferedWriter escritor = new BufferedWriter(ubicacion);
 escritor.write(CreateArea1.getText());
 escritor.close();
 } catch(Exception e){
 }
    }                                      

    private void RenameInputActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void DeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        JFileChooser fc=new JFileChooser();
 fc.showOpenDialog(null);
 File ArchivoBorrado = fc.getSelectedFile();
 if (ArchivoBorrado.delete())
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Borrado Exitoso");
 else
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error! Intenta borrarlo otra vez!");
    }                                      

    private void ReadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        JFileChooser fc=new JFileChooser();
 fc.showOpenDialog(null);
 File archivo = fc.getSelectedFile();
 try{
 FileReader fr = new FileReader (archivo);
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
 String texto="";
 String linea="";
 while(((linea=br.readLine())!=null) ){
 texto+=linea+"\n";
 }
 ReadArea.setText(texto);
 }
 catch(Exception e){
 } 
    }                                    

    private void SelectRenameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
     JFileChooser fc=new JFileChooser();
      fc.showOpenDialog(null);
      file = fc.getSelectedFile();
    }                                            
///Problems start here!!
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
      String nvo=file.getParent()+"\\"+RenameInput.getText()+".txt";
      File f2 = new File(RenameInput.getText()); //Here doesnt work!
      boolean correcto = file.renameTo(f2);//Rename method doesnt work
      if (correcto==true)
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Succesful");
       else
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El "); 
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CatFileManager.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CatFileManager.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CatFileManager.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CatFileManager.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new CatFileManager().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel Background;
    private javax.swing.JButton Create;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea CreateArea1;
    private javax.swing.JButton Delete;
    private javax.swing.JLabel DeleteDescription;
    private javax.swing.JLabel DescriptionCreate;
    private javax.swing.JLabel DescriptionSelectFile;
    private javax.swing.JLabel DescriptionSelectFile1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel DescriptionSelectFile2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel DescriptionSelectFile3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField InputCreate;
    private javax.swing.JLabel Logo;
    private javax.swing.JButton Read;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea ReadArea;
    private javax.swing.JTextField RenameInput;
    private javax.swing.JLabel RenameName;
    private javax.swing.JButton SelectRename;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private static class crear {

        public crear() {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the highlighted errors? I'm guessing there's a checked exception you're not catching

Comment: We’d love to help you. But you need to include enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem as well as the details of the error you get. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: I just posted the code! the error I get is: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.lang.Object.getParent

Comment: The IDE should be highlighting these errors long before you get to over 350 lines of code or try to run the code that won't compile. **Fix these errors early on!** And a tip: Add @user (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Object file;
```

Should be:

```
private File file; // has methods getParent() & renameTo​(File)
```

Comment: Yes, it was the solution!!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. :)